# ANTLR4 - replace op boundaries error|How to use TokenStreamRewriter to transform text from two listener events on overlapping tokens in original AST?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Hello ANTLR creators/users,

Some context - I am using PlSql ANTLR4 parser to do some lightweight transpiling of some queries from oracle sql to, let's say, spark sql. I have my listener class setup which extends the base listener.

Example of an issue - 
Let's say the input is something like -

```
SELECT to_char(to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3)||'0101') from xyz;
```

Now, I'd like to replace || with CONCAT and  to_char with CAST as STRING, so that the final query looks like -

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3) as STRING),'0101') from xyz;
```

In my listener class, I am overriding two functions from base listener to do this - concatenation and string_function. In those, I am using a tokenStreamRewriter's replace to make the necessary transformation. Since tokenStreamRewriter is evaluated lazily, I am running to issue ->

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: replace op boundaries of 
<ReplaceOp@[@38,228:234='to_char',<2193>,3:15]..[@53,276:276=')', 
<2214>,3:63]:"CAST (to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3 as STRING)"> 
overlap with previous <ReplaceOp@[@38,228:234='to_char',<2193>,3:15].. 
[@56,279:284=''0101'',<2209>,3:66]:"CONCAT 
(to_char(to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3),'0101')">
```

Clearly, the issue is my two listener functions attempting to replace/transform text on overlapping boundaries.

Is there any work around for territory overlap kind of issues for ANTLR4? I'm sure folks run into such stuff all the time probably.

I'd appreciate any workarounds, even dirty ones at this point of time :)

I did realize that ANTLR4 does not allow us to modify original AST, otherwise this would have been a little bit easier to solve.

Thanks!

Comment: How I am achieving this right now is by multiple passes -> feeding output of one pass to another. That's avoiding various listener methods from stepping onto each other's territory. Clearly, this is an issue or I am missing some fundamental concept in ANTLR4. I think mutable AST is definitely a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A look at how tokenstreamrewriter works leads to the following understanding:

- first, a list of all modification operations are built
- then, you invoke getText()
- here, there is a reduction of modification operations. The idea for example is to merge multiple insert together in one reduction. Its role is also to avoid multiple replace on same data (but i will expand on this point later).
- every token is then read, in the case there is a modification listed for the said token index, TokenStreamRewriter do the operation, otherwise it just pop the read token.

Let's have a look on how modification operations are implemented:

- for insert, tokenstream rewriter basically just adds the string to be added at the current token index, and then do an index+1, effectively going to next token
- for replace, tokenstream rewriter replace a range of tokens with the new string, and set the new index to the end of this range.

So, for tokenstreamrewriter, overlapping replaces are not possible, as when you replace you jump to the end of the range of tokens to be replaced. Especially, in the case you remove the checks of overlapping, then only the first replace will be operated, as afterwards, the token index is past the other replaces.

Basically, this has been done because there is no way to tell easily what tokens should be replaced while using overlapping replaces. You would need for that symbol recognition and matching.

So, what you are trying to do is the following (for each step, the part between '*' is what is modified):

```
*SELECT to_char(to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3)||'0101')* from xyz;
|
V
CONCAT (*to_char(to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3)*,'0101') from xyz;
|
V
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(to_number(substr(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE,1,4))-3) as STRING),'0101') from xyz;
```

to achieve your transformation, you could do so a replace of :

- 'to_char' -> 'CONCAT(CAST'
- '||' -> ' as STRING),'

And, by using a bit of intelligence while parsing your tokens, like is there a '||' in my tokens to know if it's string, you would know what to replace.

regards

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve it in multiple projects based on ANTLR is this: I translated ANTLR parse-tree to an AST written using Kolasu, an open-source library we developed at Strumenta.

Kolasu has all sort of utilities to process and mutate ASTs. For all non-trivial projects I end up doing transformations on the AST.

[Kolasu](https://github.com/strumenta/kolasu)